# Import nested submodules

Tags: python

I have a function `attach_connection_pinging` in module `mylib.tools.db`. I need to call it in `mylib/__init__.py`:

```
from .tools import db
db.attach_connection_pinging()
```

or

```
from .tools.db import attach_connection_pinging
attach_connection_pinging()
```

But I don't like this solution, because it creates unneeded names in `mylib` module.

My current solution is to auto-import needed submodules of `tools` package. `mylib/tools/__init__.py`:

```
from . import db
from . import log
```

Then in `mylib/__init__.py`:

```
from . import tools
tools.db.attach_connection_pinging()
tools.db.make_psycopg2_use_ujson()
tools.log.attach_colorsql_logging()
```

Well it's the best workaround I've found, but it's not ideal.

Ideally something like this would be nicer, but it obviously is not compiling:

```
from . import tools.db
from . import tools.log 
tools.db.attach_connection_pinging()
tools.db.make_psycopg2_use_ujson()
tools.log.attach_colorsql_logging()
```

Is there a better solution? Am I missing anything?

Comment: What's the traceback?

Comment: Also note that you can always remove names after you've used them via `del`:  `del db` or `del attach_connection_pinging`

Comment: @mgilson `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Yes, I can delete names, but it's also a workaround and an ugly one

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
from .tools import db as tools_db
from .tools import log as tools_log
```

Alternatively, your last example would work as:

```
import tools.db
```

The only catch there is that if you have some other module named tools in your python path, it will be ambiguous.

Lastly, you could choose to modify your current workaround.  In `tools/__init__.py` :

```
__all__ = ["db", "log"]
```

Then:

```
from tools import *
tools.db
```

The catch there is that "db" will also exist in your namespace and conflict with anything else that's called "db".  So I would recommend the first "import as" solution.

Comment: `import tools.db` -- __NO__, don't do that! [Absolute import](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) was introduced for a reason!

Comment: I definitely explained why that's not the best idea.  I'm just outlining his options.